# redirect function not work in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

when i run this code

```
public function LogInn()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->load->model('LogIn_Model');
        $a = $this->LogIn_Model->Create_Session($email,$password);
        if($a==1)
        {
        redirect('Hadees/word');
        }
    }
```

give an Error in Log file

```
ERROR - 2018-09-06 12:39:56 --> Severity: Error --> Call to undefined function redirect()
```

and not redirect

Comment: try with this `redirect('/Hadees/word','refresh');`

Comment: Do you have loaded helper? ( $this->load->helper('url'); )

Comment: by changing not work

Comment: yes call  $this->load->helper('url');

Comment: As it was stated already you should load the url helper, also try not to redirect with uppercase letters in your url. Even thou controllers should be named in UCFirst and the class name should also be UCFirst the url should always be everything lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

load `url` in same file or in autoload file its work

**same file**

`$this->load->helper('url');` //load url helper

**autoload file**

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`